# Does it make sense, using "count = count" in settState?

Tags: flutter

I am following a course, where the presenter makes an app thats a "to do" list.

In the State class for the main screen (that holds a ListView) he made a method called "getData()", to, err, get data to populate the list.

The class has 2 attributes: "todos" (a list[] of objects "Todo"), and count (number of itens retrieved from database).

In the body of the method, he creates a temporary list, called "todoList".
And also in the body of the method, he store the number of records read in "count".
At the end of the method, he uses the setState() method, to update the attributes and (what the setState is for) updates de GUI.

Here is his setState():

```
setState(() {
  todos = todoList; // put the temporary list "todoList" in the attribute, ok
  count = count;    // ?????? 
});
```

Does "count = count" makes any sense?

I found, here in StackOverflow, this answer to a question about what should goes inside the setState() method:

> According to the flutter docs, it is stated that:
>
> Generally it is recommended that the setState method only be used to
> wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation that might
> be associated with the change.
>
> Mainly I think that it is for readability purposes, i.e, you need to
> put in the body of setState what is changing in the new build of the
> widget, without mixing that with your computations as the first method
> in your question does.

Maybe this is the answer? He wrote "count = count" for readability purposes? (documental purposes)? Maybe to make a record that count (an attribute, representing the state) was changed?

**EDIT:**

He store something in count in this line:

```
count = result.length;
```

This line is inside a "then()" (future, etc...)

Maybe this is the answer? Since count is being updated sometime in the future, the count = count is to be sure to update the attribute?

Here is the "almost full" code:
http://carlao-ifsp-sc.com.br/todolist.dart

Comment: the implied actual line is `this.count = count`, which are two different entities. This is the case in other programming languages other than dart such as java.

Comment: Inside getData(), he writes:
count = result.length;
Does this creates another count variable (locally)?

Comment: where was the count variable defined

Comment: @carloa2005 yes probably, in which case he is required to say something like `var count = result.length`, which creates a local variable, then he proceeds to store that variable in the attribute `count` with the `count = count` line, where the first `count` is the attribute and the second is the local variable. I am not sure though as I don't see the rest of the code.

Comment: Here is the "almost full" code (its a paid online course):
http://carlao-ifsp-sc.com.br/todolist.dart

Comment: Being inside a "then" makes any difference ?

Answer (score 1):

Without the actual code, it might be a premature guess but it doesn’t make sense for me. I’ve been into flutter for quite some time and have done a few projects with it.

The only guess I can make is you are copying an external `count` into the class member `count` variable. However, in this case, we’ll typically do `this.count` to specify that we are referring to the class member `count`. Generally, `this.` is implied in Dart, so most of the time and in line with the Dart style, we don’t write it. However, in cases where we have a name conflict between the external variable and the class member variable, such as in here, we explicitly write `this.<variable_name>`.

In conclusion, this code is probably not required or should have the explicit `this.`.

Comment: Here is the complete code. I have erased some parts, because its a paid course.
http://carlao-ifsp-sc.com.br/todolist.dart
He creates attribute count, and inside getData() just access count, as in the line:
count = result.length;

Comment: Being inside a "then" makes any difference ?

Comment: I've checked the code that you sent and so far there has only been one declaration of the count variable. This means that there are no actual other variable with the same name. I've also tried to rename the symbol in VS Code and turns out in `count = count` both were actually the exact same symbol. I'm not trying to undermine the credibility of your mentor but it seems like there is no value in `count=count`.

Comment: By the way, `.then()` is simply a callback that will run if the `Future` successfully completes. Checkout `onError` if the `Future` resolves with an error and `whenComplete` which always runs regardless if the `Future` resolves successfully or with an error, much like the finally statement in try catch.

Answer (score 1):

`this.count = count` has sense

`count = count` is non-sense